# Creating an Espresso Matcher for a class with generics

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-espresso

I'm trying to create a new Matcher for espresso in order to be able to select a list item. This works fine for a simple class like Office. See this example.

```
  private fun withOffice(title: String): Matcher<Any> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<Any, Office>(Office::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("with title '$title'");
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(office: Office): Boolean {
            return office.name == title
        }
    }
}
```

However things get more difficult when bringing in generics, like in this class.

```
class KeyTranslationPair<F, S> extends Pair<F, S>
```

Trying to create a Matcher like this

```
  private fun withCompanyType(companyType: CompanyType): Matcher<Any> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<Any, KeyTranslationPair<CompanyType, String>>(KeyTranslationPair<CompanyType, String>::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("with companyType '$companyType'");
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(keyTranslationPair: KeyTranslationPair<CompanyType, String>): Boolean {
            return keyTranslationPair.key == companyType
        }
    }
}
```

results in the following error

[image]

My assumption is that kotlin get things mixed up with the java type system.
Maybe someone has an idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `KeyTranslationPair<CompanyType,Strnig>` is not a class, when is saying class means `KeyTranslationPair::class.java`, so, you can do it like :

```
return object : BoundedMatcher<Any, KeyTranslationPair<*,*>>(KeyTranslationPair::class.java)
```

And you are saying that you don't know what's inside of the `KeyTranslationPair`, and since it's a `Generic` you'll have to change the `matchesSafely` to :

```
override fun matchesSafely(item: KeyTranslationPair<*, *>?): Boolean {
   return item?.key == companyType
}
```

And also you can check if `Key` is an instance of `CompanyType` doing :

```
override fun matchesSafely(item: KeyTranslationPair<*, *>?): Boolean {
    if(item?.key is CompanyType){
        return item.key == companyType
    }
        return false
    }
```

Hope it helps.